# Did women create a space between their teeth to look beautiful in the Prophet's time?

Tags: hadith, history, women

Regarding the hadith:

> Allah has cursed those women who practise tattooing and those who get themselves tattooed, and those who remove their face hairs, and **those who create a space between their teeth artificially to look beautiful**, and such women as change the features created by Allah.
>   <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 5931](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/146)</sub>

This hadith leads naturally to the question:

**Question**: Did women create a space between their teeth to look beautiful in the Prophet's time?

In today's culture, a space between teeth (or [diastema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diastema)) is sometimes "corrected" using braces.  I.e., we do the opposite of what the hadith indicates was a thing at the time.

Answer (score -2):

It was made by the filing of the teeth, some tributes practiced the filling of the teeth, to make the teeth smaller, and make them look more childish.

Image here: http://www.odditycentral.com/videos/indonesian-tribe-believes-chiseled-teeth-make-women-beautiful.html

Correcting bad positions of the teeth is something else, as it's not only for aesthetic reasons, but because gap between teeth can lead to medical problems.

Filling of the teeth is still practiced by dentists, when teeth are broken for instance, or to have the place to install fake teeth, or to make the teeth regular.

Comment: Please explain the dowvote. Not downvote and run please.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question at all: Rebecca is clearly asking about what people were doing during the time of the Prophet, not what modern people are doing in Indonesia. You provide zero attempt to link the one to the other.

Comment: So there's a misunderstanding in the way I explain. My answer was they do this and they still do this. Read again. Thanks for your reply. Indonesia is ONLY an example, and their custom dated several thousands of years. If you are interested in anthropology, you know those custom are very very very old, they are in no mean "modern". They probably did that at the time of the Prophet, as historian found no other custom like this as far as I know. So it's a valid answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding, English is not my language.